# Data Manipulation - Basic

Tags: r

I have this table I am working on. All I need to do is to sum the rows for countries, that is, I should have one row for Afghanistan that sums all the three rows, one row for Albania....
Is there any way I can do it easily on R? I thought of using the group_by function but it ain't getting me anywhere. Your help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Iamgine `iris` data, then do it like `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(across(everything(), sum))`

Comment: In base R:
`aggregate(. ~ ref_area.label, data = b[, -2], sum)  # removes classif1.label`
or if you classif1.label is part of the grouping:
`aggregate(. ~ ref_area.label + classif1.label, data = b, sum)`